# jQuery UI Datepicker - Keyboard Navigation Event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In order to make the jQuery UI Datepicker accessible to screen readers, I'm required to populate a hidden div with the current date that is being highlighted.

The problem is that there isn't an event that is associated with keyboard navigation (CTRL + Arrow Keys).

In this case, how would I detect when the user is navigating between different dates so that I can fetch the highlighted date and populate it in the hidden div?

```
// how to detect CTRL + Arrow Key Event??
$("#datepicker").on("<CTRL + Arrow Key event>", function(){
   var message = ""+$(".ui-state-hover").html()+
                 " "+$(".ui-datepicker-month").html()+
                 " "+$(".ui-datepicker-year").html();
   $('#liveRegion').html(message);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `keydown` event to check if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key has been pressed in conjunction with an arrow key. You can query the `keyCode` of a key press to determine if an arrow key has been pressed. The arrow key `keyCode`s range from 37 to 40 (inclusive). 37 = left, 38 = up, 39 = right and 40 = down.

`evt.ctrlKey` returns `true` if it has been pressed and vice versa. `evt.keyCode >= 37 && evt.keyCode <= 40` ensures that the `#liveRegion` `div` is only updated if an arrow key has been pressed.

```
$('#datepicker').keydown(function(evt) {
  if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode >= 37 && evt.keyCode <= 40) {
    var message = "" + $(".ui-state-hover").html() +
      " " + $(".ui-datepicker-month").html() +
      " " + $(".ui-datepicker-year").html();
    $('#liveRegion').html(message);
  }
});
```

Please see the demo below for a working example. If the solution isn't suitable for your needs, don't hesitate to let me know.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/xsdtphrg/4/)**

Comment: I had figured out the same procedure before seeing this. Thought of posting the solution here but you beat me to it.