# Navigate though datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, datepicker, calendar

I never asked here, so if you notice some errors, please let me know.

I'm developing a datePicker with JQuery, I'm currently using v1.9.1 .

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make an "autoinput" while you're navigating on the calendar. 
I mean, when it starts, default date is inserted at the input,

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

so when I click on it, it should focus on today date (on calendar) and while I navigate it, change the input to the actual selected date.

If I'm being under-understandable don't doubt at asking.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this any help?  It refers to updating the datepicker value on keyboard navigation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524074/jquery-ui-datepicker-keyboard-navigation-event

Comment: I have found a different solution but this one seems easier to apply ^^ 
Thanks, sometimes we think "if I can't find a solution googling it's bc it isn't there". Really useful! How can I choose you as best answer?